# Floating button is beeing positioned beneath it's parent after changing viewport size (Chrome only)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I've encountered a problem which obviously only affects Google Chrome (not even Safari):

I have multiple `<select>` fields and a button. On mobile devices the select fields should be 100% in width, the button should be centered horizontally beneath them.

On large screen resolutions (in this case >1024px) the select fields will be positioned next to each other via `display: inline-block;` and the button should be floated right.

If you load [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNvPEK) on wide screens for the first time everything seems to look as intended. But if you now narrow the browser window beneath 1024px and then widen it again the button is beeing positioned outside it's parent.

The odd thing about this: If you then remove the `float: right;` of the button and insert it again, the button is beeing positioned correctly again.
I guess this has to do something with the button's `display: block;`. It seems like this property is not beeing replaced by `display: inline-block;` correctly. Could this be a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 0):

hello one solution is to float all the elements

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  select {
    width: auto;    
    float:left;
  }
  button {
    float: right;
  }
  .box{
    overflow:hidden;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNvPEK

Comment: In this case this would fit the needs, but in my actual project I need the elements to be aligned with `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle;`, because it's not only select fields but also text, spans and labels - all in different heights and they should be centered vertically to each other. I just wonder why this only happens in Chrome ...

Comment: you should first of all know that display:inline is a terrible way to "allign" elements, you even have one " " character between them all, and on top of it (as you see) it's not a stable construct, you can show us teh complete project so we know more. 
one solution would actually be to position the submit button absolute and the .box relative